# Obj-C - Can we point to the object whose parameter is being modified

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, this, dynamic-variables

In `ActionScript` you can do something like this:

```
character.x = character.width;
character.y = character.height;
```

or you could simply do this:

```
character.x = this.width;//`this` automagically == `character` in Actionscript (or whichever object is being modified. `this` just points to the current object being modified, it's a built in global dynamic variable)
character.y = this.height;
```

Where `this` is a dynamic variable that simply points to the object who's parameter (`x` or `y` in this case) is being edited.

..

```
objectA.property1 = objectA.property2;
```

is exactly the same as

```
objectA.property1 = this.property2;
```

Because `this` is a dynamic object oriented variable that points to the object being modified automatically.

---

Is there anything like `this` in Objective-C?

The benefits would be allowing me to create shortcuts using clang using #define.

For example, right now I may want a CLANG (***NOT*** Obj-C) shortcut for centering an object in it's superview:

```
#define centerInSuperview center = CGPointMake(this.superview.frame.size.width/2.0f, this.superview.frame.size.height/2.0f)
```

Then I could say

```
object1.centerInSuperview;
```

which would be substituted to say this:

```
object1.center = CGPointMake(this.superview.frame.size.width/2.0f, this.superview.frame.size.height/2.0f);
```

except `this` isn't a thing in Obj-c so I need something else to point to the object being modified so that I can make CLANG shortcuts.

Comment: I don't think you understand how `this` works in ActionScript.

Comment: The equivalent of `this` in Objective-C is `self`, but you would know this if you had ever bothered to read through a beginners' Objective-C tutorial.

Comment: The way I understand it, he doesn’t want `this` to mean `self`, he wants it to mean `character`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That was incredibly rude. I've never encountered someone as stuck up as you on this site, I've been coding in Objective-c for 6 years, that was extremely uncalled for. I'm not talking about `self`. Say I'm in a view controller and I have an object like a UIView and I'm modifying it's .center value, can I refer to it (the UIView) in the line of code without repeating its' name again, but instead just saying something like `this`.

Comment: @jtbandes Absolutely how `this` works in ActionScript, I've coded in that language for 10+ years.

Comment: Short answer is no, Obj-C doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw The problem is that you are asking Obj-C developers about a feature they don't know and you haven't explained the feature properly. It is probably a bit similar to Javascript's `with`. And no, there is nothing like that in Obj-C.

Comment: Does it have to be object1.centerInSuperview or would centerInSuperview(object1) be ok?

Comment: @Willeke that was just an example :) I'm more interested in the `this` part. If I really wanted centerInSuperview I would just make a method for it haha. `[object centerInSuperview];` I'm interested in the `this` part though for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

From your description `character` seems to have X, Y, Width and Height which is nothing but `CGRect` in Objective C. If so, then its a struct and you can do the simple assignment the way you showed in your question

However, from the title of the question, it appears you want to know if in Objective C, we can access parameters of an object while the same object is being modified. Well it depends, if you are simply changing the properties of the object from single thread, you can do that. So, `self.property1 = self.property2` (modified from within the class) OR `character.property1 = character.property2` (modified from outside the class) is allowed operation.

But if you talk about multiple threads then objects are not by default thread safe. While one thread is updating it, another thread should not access it. It may crash as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm more looking for a way to refer to the object being edited without using the objects name itself. So I don't want to say `character.property1 = character.property2`. I want to say `character.property1 = this.property2` where `this` becomes the object who has a property being modified or set.

Comment: This is not how it works in objective C. You might want to read Apple documentation.

Comment: I know that's not how it works? That's why I asked the question here, to see if there is a way to do it haha. I was wondering if Objective-c has any `dynamic object oriented variables`.